# Retain intermediate string using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regexp-replace

I want to append a substring to a string pattern at all occurrences in multiple python code files. However the original string follows a pattern and is not an exact same string each time.
Below are some examples of the variation:

```
Original Code:  a.b();
Want Code:      a.b().c();
```

```
Original Code:  a.b(param1=1);
Want Code:      a.b(param1=1, param2=2).c();
```

```
Original Code:  a.b(param1=1, param2=2);
Want Code:      a.b(param1=1, param2=2).c();
```

```
Original Code:  a.b(param1=D());
Want Code:      a.b(param1==D()).c();
```

```
Original Code:  X(a.b(param1=D()));
Want Code:      X(a.b(param1==D()).c());
```

---

**Update:**
Since I am attempting to replace code in a file, the file contains indention and new lines for better readability:
e.g

```
Original Code:  X(a.b(
                     param1=D()
                     )
                 );

Want Code:      X(a.b(
                     param1=D()
                     ).c()
                 );
```

```
Original Code:  X(a.b(
                     param1=D(),
                     param2="qwerty"
                     )
                 );

Want Code:      X(a.b(
                     param1=D(),
                     param2="qwerty"
                     ).c()
                 );
```

```
Original Code:  X(a.b(
                       newObj())
                 );

Want Code:      X(a.b(
                       newObj()).c()
                 );
```

I am not really concerned about parameters passed in function b. I simply need to append invocation of c() every time a.b() is invoked.

I am using the regex `'a.b(.*?)'` to detect the appropriate original code. I tried using
the following solution regexes: `a.b($1).c()` or `a.b(\1).c()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
a\.b\([^()]*\)(?=;)
```

- `a\.b` Match literally and escape the dot
- `\([^()]*\)` Match from an opening parenthesis till closing parenthesis using a negated character class
- `(?=;)` Positive lookahead, assert a `;` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L7zj6o/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yyo3OX)

And replace with the full match `\g<0>` followed by `.c()`

```
\g<0>.c()
```

For example:

```
import re

regex = r"a\.b\([^()]*\)(?=;)"

s = ("a.b();\n"
    "a.b(param1=1);\n"
    "a.b(param1=1, param2=2);")

result = re.sub(regex, r"\g<0>.c()", s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
a.b().c();
a.b(param1=1).c();
a.b(param1=1, param2=2).c();
```

---

Matching balanced parenthesis using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
a\.b(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*\))
```

The pattern matches:

- `a\.b` Match `.b`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(?>` Atomic group (no backtracking)

    - `[^()]++` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `(` or `)`
    - `|` Or
    - `(?1)` Recurse the first subpattern (group 1)
  - `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNXtKK/1/) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##bY/BDoIwDIbve4pmF1ohJMBNM3kQhslAQA6DZcxEoz47DiTxQk9t/@9P/5qnu41DNs@9NqN1YJuueTBmlHONHUCADZSMK5SI@bm4IJVh@MY8ITpIooBNzvZDN3mwYOCLKw/TiUf/ySirdCKS/W0Ea5eKdFe/oqpqIXmSZpKTR1jJWDtamKAfYLt@XG16SbvEj7Vy9Q23HyKYaNX7FvSPXMp4p8OWv3Tc2fFukD5xjcRpnr8)

```
import regex

pattern = r'a\.b(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*\))'
strings = [
    "a.b();",
    "a.b(param1=1);",
    "a.b(param1=1, param2=2);",
    "a.b(param1=d(abc=\"123\"));"
]

for s in strings:
    m = regex.match(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(f"{m.group()}.c()")
```

Output

```
a.b().c()
a.b(param1=1).c()
a.b(param1=1, param2=2).c()
a.b(param1=d(abc="123")).c()
```

Comment: The `\([^()]*\)` assumes the first closing parentheses to be correct one. Is there a way to ensure the correct closing parenthesis captured? e.g for the input `a.b(param1=d(abc="123"))`. Using suggested regex, it will replace the input to `a.b(param1=d(abc="123").c())` which is incorrect. The expected replaced string should be `a.b(param1=d(abc="123")).c()`

Comment: @learningMyWayThru If you want to match balanced parenthesis, you have to use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that supports recursion. See this pattern `a\.b(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*\))` https://regex101.com/r/lNXtKK/1 and see [this example code](https://tio.run/##bY/BDoIwDIbve4pmF1ohJMBNM3kQhslAQA6DZcxEoz47DiTxQk9t/@9P/5qnu41DNs@9NqN1YJuueTBmlHONHUCADZSMK5SI@bm4IJVh@MY8ITpIooBNzvZDN3mwYOCLKw/TiUf/ySirdCKS/W0Ea5eKdFe/oqpqIXmSZpKTR1jJWDtamKAfYLt@XG16SbvEj7Vy9Q23HyKYaNX7FvSPXMp4p8OWv3Tc2fFukD5xjcRpnr8) how you might use it

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am using this regex to replace strings in a file which is indented in different ways. So the above regex works in case where string is in a single line but not when there are new lines. I tried to use `regex.match(pattern, s, flags=DOTALL)` for it to ignore new line characters but to no avail.

Comment: @alwaysAStudent The `DOTALL` has no effect for the last pattern, as there is no dot (the single dot that matches any character) used in the pattern. What do you mean by indenting? The pattern has no anchors, so the indenting should not be a problem I think.

Comment: By indent, I mean there is are new lines and whitespaces.  I have updated the original question so I could explain the use cases better.

Comment: @alwaysAStudent Try adding `\s*` to match optional whitespace chars before the opening parenthesis https://regex101.com/r/ppTffg/1

Comment: I had tried that... You can check the additional use cases I added to main question to get a better picture of the scenario

Comment: @alwaysAStudent But the recursion matches all  balanced parenthesis after matching `a.b` See https://regex101.com/r/KbYGpS/1 What do you want to match instead?

Comment: @alwaysAStudent See this [Python demo](https://tio.run/##zZI9C8IwEIb3/Ipw052W4seorYu7q@AppBK0YmNMUqrgf68tOgg6VCff@Xm5O@6x17A/mXFd54U9uSCd3umLsCoE7YxMpAPFcca@h4w4S1cbpHW/f8PZkKjHRCCEbzCEJao4QzYg5EtAfopVThXDZI7Uje@A0YTNG/XbTtEXhVHCcK60C1eG/7lFSqOrRXZA6jQNSAinfXkM7cNbAWJfZviUIGoc4N10kMZbJIikJ2FdbgI@KlTXdw)

Comment: I simply want to append `.c()` whenever `a.b()` is invoked. The code that preceeds `a.b(....)` should be as is. The code that was originally after `a.b(...)` should shifted so that it is now append after `a.b(...).c()`.  Any characters before or rather or between the b(..) call should. remain as is, unaffected.

Comment: I think the Python demo linked above works. Thanks a ton !!!!

Comment: @alwaysAStudent Yes, the Python demo yields the requested output. You are welcome, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Pattern: `(a\.b\(.*?\))`

Replacement: `\1.c()`

Result:

```
a.b(param1=1).c();
a.b(param1=1, param2=2).c();
a.b().c();
```

https://regex101.com/r/VwxWR3/1/